# Selectively hiding child elements based on parent's class

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I've got a `table` in which each `tr` has lots of elements. I'm implementing a 'collapse' feature so that a row can be minimized, showing only a few essential elements. I'd like to accomplish this by adding a `show-on-collapse` class to the element that I want shown, and then, through my stylesheet, hide everything else.

The problem I'm encountering is that even if a given element is explicitly declared `display: block;`, it will not show if *any* of its parents are `display: none;`.

I could work around this by adding `show-on-collapse` all the way up the chain, but that's not really viable, and adds a lot of bloat to my markup.

Here's a JSFiddle showing what I'm trying to accomplish and the unsatisfactory workaround I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/89XfC/

The most relevant bit of code is the `not` selector here:

```
table {
  width: 100%;

  &.collapsed {
    td {
      &:not(.show-on-collapse) { display: none; }
            *.hide-on-collapse { display: none; }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm looking for is something to go under `&.collapsed` which enables **only** elements with `show-on-collapse` to be visible when a parent element gains the `collapsed` class. What should I do?

Comment: I don't know if SASS has anything that can target parent based on children. But what you are trying to do definitely cannot be done in css unless you add classes to the td

Comment: @Huangism Sass is *only* a CSS preprocessor. As LESS and Stylus, it outputs regular CSS and there's no parent selector in CSS (for now, will maybe be implemented one day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these essential elements can be at any level of depth in your cells, there's no simple CSS solution.
It'd be simple if the cells themselves were these essential blocks to show even when row is collapsed or their children or grand-children or ... but not a mix of all these.

You thus need a class on all ancestors of an essential block, otherwise it isn't displayed anymore. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/89XfC/2/
`td` elements are displayed as `table-cell` and not `block`; the two classes used could be optimized to a single one if there's no other need to use both class.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table1">
        <tr>
            <td class="has-essential">
                <span class='is-essential'>Show me!</span>
            </td>
            <td>Hide me!</td>
            <td class='is-essential'>Show me too!</td>
            <td class="has-essential">
                <ul class="has-essential">
                    <li>One</li>
                    <li>Two</li>
                    <li class='is-essential'>Three</li>
                    <li>Four</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <a class="collapser1">Click me</a>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.collapsed td,
.collapsed td * {
    display: none;
}
.collapsed td.is-essential,
.collapsed td.has-essential {
    display: table-cell;
}
.collapsed .is-essential,
.collapsed .has-essential {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off of FelipeAls's answer (which you should accept since his answer is as good as you'll be able to do most likely), here is what it would look like using SCSS.

```
table {
    width: 100%

    &.collapsed {
        td {
            display: none

            & * {
                display: none
            }

            &.is-essential, &.has-essential {
                display: table-cell
            }
        }

        .is-essential, .has-essential {
            display: block
        }
    }
}
```